# Problem using stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, nsstring, compiler-warnings

I'm having some problems working with NSStrings in Objective C... the code below returns a warning, saying:

"'NSString' may not respond to '-stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString:withString:"

```
NSString* NewWord = [Word stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString:@"!" 
                                                   withString:@""];
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated - thanks

Comment: This is where code completion is your friend.

Comment: No need to downvote, folks.  Perfectly legitimate question.  Note also that convention is for variables to start with a lowercase letter;  `NewWord` should be `newWord`.

Comment: I'm surprised we don't get more occurrences of this kind of question.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me... I do remember being told that a while ago but I guess it just slipped out of my mind

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a spelling error. The method name is actually [`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW6).

Comment: *Facepalm* Haha thanks very much I didn't notice that

Answer (score 0):

I find that the LLVM complier provides a better warning in this case:

warning: method '-stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString:withString:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Comment: I don't think it's really that much better; a *really* good message would suggest an existing method name to the user, if it "detects" a possible typo.

Comment: I agree... if the compiler could literally point out spelling mistakes to people, then that would put an end to people like me looking stupid by posting stupid questions on forums!